# Flutter Push with firebase_messaging => get all Topics

Tags: dart, flutter

for my flutter project I use firebase_messaging for push notifications. 
It works great!

Now I wanted to extend my App with topics...
Is it possible to get all activated Topics for one push-user/id?
I cant see anything in the code.

Otherwise I have to save the activated Topics in my APP and send them to each time to firebase? But it could happen that a user deactivates/unsubscribes a topic and if firebase doesnt get the unsubscription, this topic is activated in Firebase but not in my app.... this is not very nice I think?
perhaps somebody can help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: so what is the issue .? use - `FirebaseMessaging _msg = FirebaseMessaging();` & Then  `_msg.subscribeToTopic('all');` topic name & then you send notification to that topic.

Comment: I want to make a settingspage with some switches for each topic to (de)activate each topic.

For this the app has to know to which topic the user has subscribed....